# Unable to use logical operator while comparing strings for input validation in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, logical-operators

I am attempting to prompt a user for input and then validate if the users input matches one  of two different options, and will exit if a correct input was not given.

In the example, I am asking the user to enter 'BOB' or 'TOM' as valid inputs, however when I run this code I will always get the message 'Server type not entered correctly', even when I enter **BOB** as an input for the prompt.

```
$ServerType = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Server Type (BOB or TOM)'

If ($ServerType -ne  "BOB" -Or $ServerType -ne  "TOM")
{
Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Server type not entered correctly'
}
```

I have also tried

```
If (($ServerType -ne  "BOB") -or ($ServerType -ne  "TOM"))
{
Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Server type not entered correctly'
}
```

However, when I only test for one value it works:

```
If ($ServerType -ne  "BOB")
{
Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Server type not entered correctly'
}
```

Any ideas why I might be getting this?

Comment: The operator you should be using in this case should be `-and`. `$true OR $false = $true` which is why you are always entering that condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in my comment, the logical operator in this case should be `-and` but allow me to give you 2 examples where your validation could be improved.

- First one is using the [`-match` \ `-notmatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#-match-and--notmatch) comparison operators, which allows the use of `regex`:

```
$ServerType = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Server Type (BOB or TOM)'

if($ServerType -notmatch '^(bob|tom)$')
{
    Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Server type not entered correctly'
}
```

- Second one, is using a [ValidateSet attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1#validateset-attribute):

```
try
{
    [validateset('bob','tom')]
    $ServerType = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Server Type (BOB or TOM)'
}
catch
{
    Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Server type not entered correctly'
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
This is great, I never knew about the -match/-notmatch operators. 
Also, the ValidateSet attribute is perfect for my usage and also something I have never seen.

Comment: @Bajan happy to help, and glad that you're learning something new :) `[validateset(...)]` might be a more advanced thing, you would normally see it on advanced functions but you can also you see it for this test case.